# Python List sorting with custom key

Tags: python, sorting

I am a beginner and looking to sort the following list so that all values starting with 'M' are first, then 'S', then 'R', then 'G' and finally 'Z'

```
icd10 = ['Z47.89', 'M54.5', 'M54.9', 'G89.29', 'S83.519a', 'S82.512d', 'R53.2']
```

The order of the character after the first letter does not matter.

So example result should be something like:

```
icd10 = ['M54.5', 'M54.9', 'S83.519a', 'S82.512d', 'R53.2', 'G89.29', 'Z47.89']
```

So far I have played around with the lambda function, but can't find answers on how to utilize a sorting key.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Almost any tutorial on `sort` will include a section on how to use a sort key, including a custom lambda function.  I don't understand how you're not able to use it.  Please supply the failing code attempt.

Comment: You could translate the first character to an integer, e.g. `values.sort(key=lambda value: lookup.index(value[0]))` where lookup is `'MSRGZ'`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
icd10 = ['Z47.89', 'M54.5', 'M54.9', 'G89.29', 'S83.519a', 'S82.512d', 'R53.2']
def key(data):
    if data[0] == "M":
        return 1
    elif data[0] == "S":
        return 2
    elif data[0] == "R":
        return 3
    elif data[0] == "G":
        return 4
    elif data[0] == "Z":
        return 5
icd10.sort(key=key)
print(icd10)
```